# Múltipla consulta SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query

Não sou muito experiente com linguagem SQL, como eu poderia fazer uma consulta funcionar desta forma:

```
SELECT *,
( SELECT marca.* FROM marca WHERE marca.id = produtos.id ) AS nome_marca
FROM produtos WHERE id = 5
```

Oque eu quero que retorne é tudo `*` da tabela `produtos` e tudo `*` da tabela `marca` guardando em `nome_marca`.

Se eu tentar selecionar apenas 1 campo como assim ->`( SELECT marca.nome FROM marca WHERE marca.id = produtos.id )` o código roda normal. Mas ele não roda se eu tentar selecionar todos com `*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso resolve o seu problema:

```
SELECT *, ( SELECT top 1 marca.* FROM marca WHERE marca.id = produtos.id ) AS nome_marca
FROM produtos 
WHERE id = 5
```

O problema é que da forma que estava, o *sql* não entende que a *subconsulta* terá apenas um retorno (`marca.id = produtos.id`), por isso o erro. Quando você manda retornar apenas o `top 1`, ele entende que trará apenas uma linha.

Uma alternativa seria você usar [`join`](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-join-entenda-como-funciona-o-retorno-dos-dados/31006), assim deverá ter o mesmo resultado:

```
SELECT *
FROM produtos
JOIN marca ON marca.id = produtos.id
WHERE produtos.id = 5
```

---

**editado após comentário**

[@Anorak](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/120493/anorak), o uso de mais um *join* é basicamente o que você escreveu em comentário, o problema é que sobrou uma vírgula; mas ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM produtos 
JOIN categoria ON categoria.id = produtos.id
JOIN marca ON marca.id = produtos.id 
WHERE produtos.id = 5
```

Comment: Usando o `JOIN` resolveu meu problema, mas por motivo didáticos como eu poderia por exemplo usar + de 1 `JOIN` como esse exemplo:
`SELECT * FROM produtos
JOIN categoria ON categoria.id = produtos.id,
JOIN marca ON marca.id = produtos.id
WHERE produtos.id = 5`

Comment: @Anorak, editei a resposta, veja se ficou claro..